How do you actually get faster?
In Mario Kart 8 Deluxe, there doesn’t really seem to be a way to get faster than your opponents, especially when going against actual people.
Sure, you can drift, hit ZR when you’re doing a jump, drive over boosters on the ground, not crash (duh), and control airtime when the glider is out, but that seems to be about it. If everyone is competent, and can pull that off, I don’t see a way to beat your opponents.
How are you actually supposed to beat your opponents if they’re ahead of you?

For this question, assume no items are used (i.e no mystery boxes), everyone is using the same car setup, and everyone is a competent driver (e.g no crashing, knows how to drift, etc).

"especially when going against actual people" - to be fair, thanks to the Mario Kart severe rubberband AI com controlled opponent are programmed to be far faster than you and will always catch up no mater what (in some games damage/acceleration times are ever disabled for them if they are off-screen)

I can think of 3 options:

The more coins you collect, higher the speed. You should always have 10 of them to maximize your speed. You also get a mini-boost when collecting a coin.

The Slipstream:



If a player trails behind another racer (or tailgates) for a certain period of time, the player's vehicle will receive a speed boost similar to the Mini-Turbo. This can be used to ram the vehicle the player is slipstreaming behind and race ahead into a higher place.


Not a way to be faster, but a good solution is to learn every shortcut and be able to perform them even without Super mushrooms (it's possible, sometimes).


If you were faster than everyone else, then that would put you at an unfair advantage. Like just about every racing game, your speed is down to:
1 - what car you select
2 - your racing line
3 - what mistakes you make
Of course, in Mario Kart you have the added bonus that you've got items to disrupt your opponent, but if you have essentially a "level playing field" with everyone playing exactly the same, then it simply comes down to what position you start in (as that has a physical effect on the starting grid), any "rubber-banding", and how each player bounces off the others in the inevitable bottle-necks.
Edit - coins do make you go faster but are a finite resource or take time to respawn, so it depends who can get to them first.
